# qTip not working with Zend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework, qtip2

I'm trying to add a help button in a Zend form using qTip 2. The button is a simple image, and I would like to open a pop-in when the image is clicked.

Here my code:

in Booostrap.php:

```
protected function _initView() {
    ...
    $view->headLink()
            ->appendStylesheet('/css/jquery/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css')
            ->appendStylesheet('/css/jquery/jquery.qtip.min.css');
}

protected function _initJQuery() {
    ...
    $view->jQuery()
            ->setLocalPath('/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')                
            ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js')
            ->addJavascriptFile('/js/jquery.qtip.min.js')
            ->enable()
            ->uiEnable();
}
```

In my view:

```
<?php
    $this->headscript()->appendScript('$(data-tooltip!="").qtip({content: {attr: \'data-tooltip\'}});');
?>
...
<img data-tooltip="thing" src="/images/repo/help-22x22.png"/>
```

And the rendered result in my browser:

```
<link href="/css/jquery/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/css/jquery/jquery.qtip.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
$(data-tooltip!="").qtip({content: {attr: 'data-tooltip'}});    //-->
</script>
...
<img data-tooltip="truc" src="/images/repo/help-22x22.png"/>
```

which is what I wanted to get. Problem is, the tooltip doesn't show up. Not even is an event fired when I click on the picture, according to the Javascript console. So my idea i wrong, but I can't understand why. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think that the problem is here: `$(data-tooltip!="")` instead of `$('[data-tooltip!=""]')`. 

An other problem is your call is before the tag img so use `InlineScript` ìnstead of `headscript` 

To Finish, I think should precise de name of the tag (`img`) in the selector.
Try to replace

```
$this->headscript()->appendScript('$(data-tooltip!="").qtip({content: {attr: \'data-tooltip\'}});');
```

By

```
$this->InlineScript()->appendScript('$(\'img[data-tooltip!=""]\').qtip({content: {attr: \'data-tooltip\'}});');
```

Comment: Your first solution was actually working, combined with Jai's. When I added the missing syntax AND used a $(document).ready(), it worked. I had 2 mistakes in my code, and only tested one correction at a time, so it never worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but your qtip initialization has to be in `doc ready`:

```
<?php
   $this->headscript()->appendScript('$(function(){// here qtip code});');
?>
```

Comment: I already tried that, for no avail. Though, I think the JQuery lifecycle should be managed by Zend somehow, if anyone has a lead.

Comment: Ok, it works, as explained above. You and doydoy44 provided each a piece of the solution.

Comment: Well glad this helped you. Actually i was about to post the same but didn't get the time for it.